# Primefaces 3.5/CSS - selectOneMenu and button vertical align

Tags: css, primefaces, themes

In Primefaces 3.5 vertical align of `p:selectOneMenu` and `button` is weird when you put them in one line. My use case is: user chooses option from menu and then click button to activate it. Issue is - both components have to be in the same line (table row).

XHTML is really easy:

```html
<h:form>
    <p:selectOneMenu>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="test" itemValue="test"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:commandButton value="GO"/>
</h:form>
```

Unfortunately result is not what I expect: [image: wrong align]

My expectation is rather something line this: [image: wanted align 1] or [image: wanted align 2]

I tried to research rendered HTML code with Firebug, but honestly, it's hard for me to found any CSS margin, padding, left, top, or anything like that could help me.

Anyone struggled with such issue (and - hopefully - solved it)?

Comment: **waste**'s solution works. Though, if you wanted to apply this change to all selectOneMenus (tested with PF 5.3) without the need to reference a styleClass, the class you would want to override is `.ui-selectonemenu`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution is:

```html
    <style type="text/css">
        .selectMenu { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
    </style>
    <h:form>
        <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="selectMenu">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="test" itemValue="test"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:commandButton value="GO"/>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks, was solving this with `margin-bottom: -5px` but this is a much cleaner.  I just added `.ui-selectonemenu { vertical-align: top }` to override primefaces.css (display was already inline-block) and they all look fine now.

Comment: `vertical-align: middle` also works, but `vertical-align: baseline` (which is the default) does not.  A real combo-box has a true baseline, but the PrimeFaces version is not a real combo-box and seems to have no baseline.  Acccording to [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align), “If the box does not have a baseline, align the bottom margin edge with the parent's baseline.”  I believe this and the lack of a true baseline explain the behavior we're seeing.

Comment: still valid for PF 6.0

Comment: @VGR I have been researching a 'true' baseline fix - others are just workarounds with a different visual result. No luck so far ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a panelGrid for auto align easily both of them.

```
<h:form>
  <h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:selectOneMenu>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="test" itemValue="test"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:commandButton value="GO"/>
  </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Tempting... But that means I have to put additional ``table`` element just to align two components. I was rather thinking about some CSS work here.